# Getting BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException in Spring while using BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to run a Spring example using `BeanPostProcessor`.

Below is the bean post processor

```
public class DisplayNamePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    DisplayNamePostProcessor(){
        System.out.println("DisplayNamePostProcessor instantiated");
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization for bean "+beanName);

        return this;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization for bean "+beanName);
        return this;
    }

}
```

here, is the spring configuration file

```
    <bean id="car" class="com.core.Car" >
            <property name="wheel" value="four" />
        </bean>
<bean class="com.core.DisplayNamePostProcessor"></bean>
```

Here, is my bean class

```
public class Car {

    private String wheel; 

    public String getWheel() {
        return wheel;
    } 
    public void setWheel(String wheel) {
        this.wheel = wheel;
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        System.out.println("application context loaded");
        Car car = context.getBean("car", Car.class);
    }
}
```

On running the above main method, I am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'car' must be of type [com.core.Car], but was actually of type [com.core.DisplayNamePostProcessor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
```

Can someone please let me know what Ia m doing wrong and how to resolve this exception. Also, what is the root cause of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) beans you declare will be picked up by the `ApplicationContext` bean factory and used. Your implementation does this

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization for bean "+beanName);

    return this;
}
```

Instead of doing anything to the target `bean`, it simply returns itself. It thus overrides all beans it processes with a `DisplayNamePostProcessor` bean.